# Dynamically Update fields through Input field and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically update a text field through an input field.  This will then be linked to a dropdown selection with values.  I also need to show a due date to show 30 days in advance from today's date.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="payment">Payment:</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" onChange="myfunction()"/>
    <br /><br />
    <label for="delivery">Delivery:</label>
    <select id="delivery" name="delivery">
        <option value="1">Fast</option>
        <option value="2">Medium</option>
        <option value="3">Slow</option>
    </select>    
</div>
<br />
<div>
Payment Breakdown: <br /><br />
Payment:
<div name="amount" id="amount"></div>
Freight:   
<div name="delivery" id="delivery"></div> 
Total Payment:
<div name="total" id="total"></div>
Due Date:    
<div name="date" id="date"></div>    
</div>
```

I'm struggling with the Javascript part though and fitting it all together.

I've gotten as far as this and now I'm stuck. (Not very far I know)

```
function myFunction()
{
var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
var delivery = parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").val());
total = amount + delivery
$("#total").html(total);
};
```

I've looked at examples on Stackoverflow and Google but nothing seems similar to what I'm trying to achieve.  Although I know the answer is out there, I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to this. Here I have an `updateCost()` function which is called when the amount is changed or the delivery is changed. I also added code to handle the due date.

Remove the inline `onchange` event from the amount:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateCost()
{
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var delivery = parseInt($('#delivery').val());

    var total = amount + delivery
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#amountdiv").html(amount);
    $("#deliverydiv").html(delivery);

    // handle the due date
    var todayPlus30 = new Date();
    todayPlus30.setDate(todayPlus30.getDate()+30);
    var dateStr = todayPlus30.getDate() + "/" + (todayPlus30.getMonth()+1) + "/" + todayPlus30.getFullYear();

    $('#date').html(dateStr);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amount').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#delivery').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
});
```

Your original code has a few problems:

1. The wrong case on the inline function call
2. The use of `this` within the function when `this` is not actually any of your elements (you didn't pass it as an argument).
3. The use of `amount` in the calculation when `amount` is an input element, not a value.
4. From a usability point of view, it would only try to update when the amount is changed, I think it would be better to update on both change of the amount and delivery.

Comment: Thank you @MrCode, although as mentioned.  Why don't the values appear in the 'amount' and 'delivery' div, when leaving the input field.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work before you edited your post.  Thought I was doing something wrong.  It's strange as it also disables the dropdown. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnystudent/3TMK8/1/)

Comment: You have the textbox and the div both with the same id `amount`. Change the div to `id="amountdiv"`. I updated the answer with the jQuery change. Same with `delivery`, you should change to `deliverydiv`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3TMK8/3/